# How to redirect http to https using iptables

Tags: iptables, web-server

I have purchased a valid SSL certificate. I have a web server running on port 443, that displays correctly when I visit https://mydomain.com. How can I use iptables to forward all http requests to use https?

Thanks

Comment: You should not try to provide an answer within your question... What you are asking is simply impossible. You cannot use iptables. Use something at the (HTTP) protocol level.

Comment: tcp/ip is a protocol, do you mean at the application level?

Comment: At the HTTP protocol (yes, application layer) level .

Comment: How am I providing an answer within my question?

Comment: You suppose it is possible with iptables. It is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this directly with iptables, because doing the "redirect" at layer 3/4 will not allow SSL negotiation to take place, as the client's browser will still being using plain HTTP.

What you need to do is use an HTTP 302 (or other 300-level) response code to redirect users to the HTTPS verison of your site.  This can be done in many ways:

- URL rewriting module for your webserver software (e.g. [Using the HTAccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess))
- Redirect the client [using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript)
- [META tags in the document served by the HTTP version of your site](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml)
- Code in the server-side code for the document served by the HTTP version of your site
- Redirects in an infrastructure layer above your webserver (e.g. load balancer)

Comment: Using a 301 redirect is best for SEO.

Comment: @toppledwagon In my ideal world 303 would be best *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

You don't redirect between protocols using iptables. You could at most redirect a certain connection using the same protocol to another IP and/or port using iptables.

Thus, what you are asking is not possible.

Just have your webserver redirect the page. Or have an empty index page on the http site that redirects to the https site.